# What is best investment which is full recession proof?

Tags: income-tax, india, investing, investment-strategies, tax-exemption

I'm a 30 yr old guy and don't have that much investment till date. Can anyone suggest all type of investments in India which are recession proof? Im really unaware about all these investment things. Help appreciated!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by recession proof? Or are you saying Inflation proof?

Comment: I meant, recession shouldn't harm or lessen my profit on investment.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone suggest all type of investments in India which are recession proof?

There are no such investments. Quite a few think bullions like Gold tend to go up [during recession](https://www.caseyresearch.com/articles/what-happens-gold-if-we-enter-recession-or-depression), which is true to an extent; however there are [enough articles](http://www.economicpolicyjournal.com/2016/02/the-myth-that-gold-is-great-performer.html) that show it is not necessarily true.

There are no fool proof investments. The only fool proof way is to mitigate risks. Have a diversified portfolio that has Debt [Fixed Deposits, Bonds] and equity [Stocks], Bullion [Gold], etc. And stay invested for long as the effects tend to cancel out in the long run.

Comment: You mention investing in gold. Are you recommending buying gold as a long term investment?

Comment: @Dheer fair enough - I did not read your answer closely enough :).  Comment removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a recession proof investment.Every investment is bound to their ups and downs.

If you buy land, a change in law can change the whole situation it may become worthless, same applies for home as well.

Gold - dependent on world economy.

Stock - dependent on world economy

Best way is to stay ever vigilant of world around you and keep shuffling from one investment to another balance out your portfolio.

"The most valuable commodity I know of is information." - Wall Street -movie